# Find recursively all paths with specific name with specific conditions

Tags: perl

I'm trying to recursively find all the files which are called `test.json` in a specif directory and insert them into an array.
They are always located in `json_files_<id_num>` (`<id_num>` = some unique id number) directory which always located in `log_dir`. But `log_dir` can also contain `full_json_files` directory which also have this file.
I am trying to create a utility which iterates over all paths in the input directory and finds all the paths to the `test.json` file. 
But if we have `full_json_files` directory in the `log_dir` directory, I would like to take `full_json_files/test.json` instead of `json_files<id_num>`.

I'll try to make more sense with an example. Consider the following hierarchy:

```
- somePath1
    - log_dir
        - json_files_12345
            - test.json
- somePath2
    - log_dir
        - json_files_543
            - test.json 
        - full_json_files
            - test.json
- somePath3
    - log_dir
        - json_files_123
```

Expected output:

```
somePath1/log_dir/json_files_12345/test.json
somePath2/log_dir/full_json_files/test.json
```

Please note that `somePath1,somePath2,somePath3` are all paths that are starting from the input directory (`$main_dir`).
I though of using `File::Find` module, so I did something basic:

```
find( 
    sub { push (@dirs,$File::Find::name) if(basename($File::Find::name) eq "test.json"); }, 
    $main_dir
);
```

It will insert to `@dirs` all the paths to the `test.json` files. But I would like to somehow to combine the above condition in this `sub`.
Also, I would like to declare this subroutine separate and pass by reference (by using `&`), and do all of the checks in that subroutine.
How should I do it? `File::find` is a good way to solve this issue? if not, what another way to do it?

It should be very basic, but for some reason, I struggle to continue from that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using post processing of `@files`, and a temporary hash `%full_json_dir` to record if a directory contains a "full" file:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw(basename dirname);
use File::Find;

my @files;
my $main_dir = '.';
my %full_json_dir;

find( sub { wanted( \@files, $_ ) }, $main_dir);

sub wanted {
    my ( $files, $name ) = @_;

    if ( $name eq 'test.json' ) {
        push @$files, $File::Find::name;
        my $pdir = dirname $File::Find::dir;
        my $full_dir = ( (basename $File::Find::dir) eq "full_json_files" ) ? 1 : 0;
        if ( exists $full_json_dir{$pdir} ) {
            if ( !$full_json_dir{$pdir} ) {
                $full_json_dir{$pdir} = $full_dir;
            }
        }
        else {
            $full_json_dir{$pdir} = $full_dir;
        }
    }
} 

my @files2;
for my $file (@files) {
    my $dir = dirname $file;
    my $pdir = dirname $dir;
    if ( $full_json_dir{$pdir} == 1) {
        push @files2, $file;
        $full_json_dir{$pdir} = 2;
    }
    elsif ( $full_json_dir{$pdir} == 0 )  {
        push @files2, $file;
    }
}


say for @files2;
```

**Output**:

```
./somePath1/log_dir/json_files_12345/test.json
./somePath2/log_dir/full_json_files/test.json
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. Is it possible to show change the  `sub { wanted( \@files, $_ ) }` part? So it will be something like: `find(  \&wanted , $main_dir);`? (of course without declaring another sub).

Comment: Thanks! Yes you can change `find( sub { wanted ... }, $dir)` to `find (\&wanted, $dir)`. The only catch is that you will miss the explicitness of the `@files` lexical array argument passed to the sub `wanted()`. Now, it is instead passed implicitly, which can lead to unclear code and later strange bugs.. Why would like to change the calling syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Requisite plug for [`IO::All`](https://metacapan.org/pod/IO::All):

```
perl -MIO::All -E 'say for io("./mydir")->filter(sub{ /test.json/ })->All_Files'
```

Or, as a script instead of a one-liner:

```
use IO::All;
my @testfiles = io->dir("./mydir")->filter(sub{ /test.json/ })->All_Files;
print join "\n", @testfiles ;
```

Sorry **:-)**